# Where do I ask a question about development, product management, UX design... when considering a career change towards software development?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a professional completely OUTSIDE of the software development field, but I'm considering a career change in that direction.

I'm interested in learning about development, product management, UX design, and any other niche jobs in the field that I don't know about but might be suited for based on previous training/experience.

Where would I ask such a question?

Comment: [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: btw, congrats for doing it right. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *might* be suitable on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but don't be too disappointed if it gets closed - career advice questions are on the brink of being off-topic even there.

From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Can I ask career advice questions?
>
> Yes, within reason. Most career advice questions are specific to the poster's situation and run the risk of being closed. Try to generalize your situation into a good subjective

Comment: See this meta Programmers question - [Are Career Advice questions useful to anyone except the poster?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster) and the graphic on this answer [Resume Advice](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/resume-feedback/1616#1616)

Answer (score 2):

You should try http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ as a reference to search around; though you can't ask a *direct* question, you could always find some answers :).